# Entity framework ctp5 one to many relationship using data annotation

Tags: .net, data-annotations, entity-framework-ctp5

I have two classes university and department, suppose there is one to many relationship i.e one university has many departments

```
public class University
{   
    public string UniversityId;
    public string UniversityName;
    public List<Department> Departments;
}

public class Department
{
    public string DepartmentId;
    public string DepartmentName;
}
```

I want to map this relationship using Entity framework data annotation feature ctp5
and also can someone point me to any good tutorial of data annotation features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx
Euphoric is correct you do not need annotations.  However if you want to have multiple relationships between objects you may need to use the fluent API.

So the only code you would need is

```
public class University
{   
    public string UniversityId { get; set; }
    public string UniversityName { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public University University{ get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is no need for anotation. If you have both classes in your context, then framework itself recognizes this relation and creates tables as required.

And to be sure create reference from Department to University.

Comment: what do you mean by this "And to be sure create reference from Department to University"